# Ejecutar sql en java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Tengo el siguiente código :

```
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Mi clase :

```
public class DataBaseServiceImpl implements IDataBaseService {

  @Autowired
  private IDataBaseDao databaseDao;

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<Jdbc> findAll() {
    return databaseDao.findAll();
  }
```

y mi otra clase

```
@Repository
public class DataBaseDao implements IDataBaseDao {

@Autowired
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Jdbc> findAll() {
    return (List<Jdbc>) hibernateTemplate.find("from Jdbc");
}
```

Esto funciona sin problemas, pero yo quiero ejecutar una sql, ahora tengo esto :

```
@Override
public List<Column> getColumns(Jdbc jdbc, String tableName) throws SQLException {
    List<Column> result = new ArrayList<Column>();
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection(jdbc);
        stmt = connection.createStatement();

            query = "Select column_name AS field,data_type as type from user_tab_columns where table_name= '" + tableName + "'";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            result.add(new Column(rs.getString("field"), rs.getString("type")));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeConnection(rs, stmt, connection);
    }

    return result;
}
```

¿cómo puedo ejecutar también esa consulta sin abrir una conexión porque ya en la clase `DataBaseServiceImpl` la tengo inyectada.

Comment: ¿Como tienes inyectada la conexion?

Comment: pregunta actualizada

Comment: No sé si es tu intención, pero lo que tienes se lee como "tengo una base de datos con una tabla, y cada fila de esa tabla son los datos de conexión a **otra** base de datos que es la que tiene los datos..." ¿es correcto?

Comment: DataBaseServiceImpl  sigue sin tener una conexion inyectada. Lo que tienes inyectado es el DAO.

Comment: acabo de actulizar pregunta

Comment: @sjuan76 si es correcto pero ahora quiero usar solo una, sino que una se conectaba por hibernate y la otra por jdbc, ahora todas las tablas estan en la conexion de hibernate por lo que necesito reutilizar esas query

Comment: Conviertelas a querys de Hibernate.

Comment: Perdona pero tu última frase es bastante confusa... ¿Quizás quieres decir que ahora todo el mecanismo de `List<Jdbc>` sobra y la tabla de datos está en la misma conexión que usas para Hibernate?

Comment: @sjuan76 exacto ya no utilizare la tabla jdbc pero quiero serguir manteniendo hibernate para ejecutar las querys y ya no jdbc

Comment: A ver, como comenta @sirdaiz, si trabajas con Hibernate haz las cosas tal como Hibernate las hace. Olvídate de la conexión, inyecta un `HibernateTemplate` o un `SessionFactory` y trabaja a partir de ahí. A partir de un `Session` puedes ejecutar SQL con `createSQLQuery`, aunque recomiendo que abraces el "Hibernate way of life" en vez de acabar con un pastiche de entities y SQL nativo.

Comment: tengo ya inyectacto el SessionFactory en HibernateTemplate, cuando hago hibernateTemplate.createSQLQuery no existe ese método

Comment: Del `SessionFactory` obtienes un `Session`

Answer (score 1):

Como tienes hibernate configurado y el manejo de sesiones lo hace Spring

```
Query query = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
                    "Select column_name AS field,data_type as type from user_tab_columns where table_name = ? ")
                               .setString(0, tableName);
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer());
List<Map<String, Object>> resultId = query.list();
```

Lo ideal es que generaras un DTO y mapearas tu resultSet al DTO pero el List igual te sirve. En el List te va a devolver la lista con un elemento por registro donde cada elemento es un Map que contiene la relación del nombre de la columna como key y el value como el valor de la columna